# Java units of measurement library addition and subtraction returning incorrect values

Tags: java, jscience, jsr363

I'm using the reference implementation of JSR363. I've tried many variations of this but I'll give this code as an example.

```
ServiceProvider provider = ServiceProvider.current();
QuantityFactory<Length> lengthFactory = provider.getQuantityFactory(Length.class);
Quantity<Length> first = lengthFactory.create(5, Units.METRE.divide(100.0));
Quantity<Length> second = lengthFactory.create(3, Units.METRE);
System.out.println(second.add(first));
```

This prints 503.0 m. Clearly something is very wrong and this should be 3.05 m. I find it very hard to believe that this is actually a bug with the library and I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: `CENTI(SI.METRE)` would be an alternative. Isn't there a JScience forum?

Comment: @JoopEggen Same thing happens when using CENTI, I'll try to look for forums but technically it's not JScience anymore.

Comment: Look for a newer version of the library, This must be a not unit-tested build where someone seriously erred.

Comment: I'm using the 'final' release of the reference implementation for JSR-363, not sure where to look for something newer or more stable than that. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/tec/units/unit-ri/1.0/

Comment: Seems like with every test I do divide and multiply are switched. So calling multiple actually divides and calling divide actually multiplies...

Comment: Could you test that in a new project? It simply is too bizarre.

Comment: Please note, SI.METRE is also available on top of JSR 363, but the JScience precursor never went final so far. JScience 4 did, but there is no JScience 5 release I am aware of. As one of the JSR 363 Spec Leads is the creator of JScience, I know he may release something based on JSR 363, but can't say, when. The "Full SI" module on top of JSR 363 can be found here: https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/si-units

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking into this a bit I've been able to reproduce the oddities in question. It appears that using the `multiply()` or the `divide()` methods when passing a `Unit` into a QuantityFactory has strange effects. In example:

```
Quantity firstQuant = quantFactory.create(10.0,Units.METRE)
Quantity secondQuant = quantFactory.create(20.0,Units.METRE.divide(10.0))
System.out.println(secondQuant.add(firstQuant))
```

outputs the following: `20.5 dm`. Even when using `MetricPrefix`, which seems to be the default method of setting non base SI units, it seems to generate extremely inaccurate `Units`. Using the following:

```
Quantity secondQuant = quantFactory.create(20.0,MetricPrefix.KILO(Units.METRE))
```

outputs `10020.0 km` which is nowhere near accurate. However, the following:

```
Quantity firstQuant = quantFactory.create(10.0,Units.METRE)
Quantity secondQuant = quantFactory.create(20.0,Units.METRE)
System.out.println(secondQuant.divide(10.0).add(firstQuant))
```

outputs `12.0 m`, which is obviously the correct answer.

In honesty the best solution is to simply not use those operations in the creation of the `Quantity` and to convert to other units of measurement using the built in `getConverter()` of `MetricPrefix` enums.

The better way to create `Quantities` is to use `Quantities.getQuantities()`

Comment: That's correct, Quantities.getQuantity() does not share some of the problems found in NumberQuantity at the moment. The RI version of the default QuantityFactory returns a new NumberQuantity. While the Java SE 8 version uom-se doesn't. It was addressed there, but not merged back into the RI. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thus, if you're able to chose and run Java SE 8 or 9, try uom-se, it should work there;-)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the insight provided by Beryllium, I can confirm the reported behavior and have tracked down the problem to a bug in the reference implementation. I took the liberty of [reporting the issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/UNITSOFMEASUREMENT-195) and my findings along with a proposed fix.

Indeed, the method `doubleValue(Unit<Q>)` of `NumberQuantity`, which is used under the hood in conversion steps, erroneously computes the inverse transformation between units. This explains OP's observation that multiplication and division by constant factors appear to be reversed when applied as unit transformations.

Since the default quantity factory exclusively returns objects of type `NumberQuantity`, all quantities created this way are affected. However, other types like `DoubleQuantity` seem to work correctly. As suggested in the answer by Beryllium, they can be created by means of `Quantities.getQuantities(<value>, <unit>)`. The following code snippet demonstrates that conversion breaks for a `NumberQuantity` obtained from the default factory, but works correctly for a `DoubleQuantity`:

```
package test.jsciunits;

import javax.measure.spi.ServiceProvider;
import javax.measure.Quantity;
import javax.measure.quantity.Length;
import javax.measure.spi.QuantityFactory;
import tec.units.ri.quantity.Quantities;
import static tec.units.ri.unit.Units.*;
import static tec.units.ri.unit.MetricPrefix.*;

public class JScienceUnits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceProvider provider = ServiceProvider.current();
        QuantityFactory<Length> lengthFactory = provider.getQuantityFactory(Length.class);

        Quantity<Length> q = lengthFactory.create(5.0, METRE);
        Quantity<Length> r = Quantities.getQuantity(5.0,  METRE);

        System.out.println("q = " + q + ", q.to(CENTI(METRE)) = " + q.to(CENTI(METRE)));
        System.out.println("r = " + r + ", r.to(CENTI(METRE)) = " + r.to(CENTI(METRE)));
    }
}
```

This produces

```
q = 5.0 m, q.to(CENTI(METRE)) = 0.05 cm
r = 5.0 m, r.to(CENTI(METRE)) = 500.0 cm
```

where the second line shows a correct conversion result.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the detailed description on how to reproduce the issue.

The **NumberQuantity** class was reported to cause a similar issue by another developer (who explained his problem by email) So we're aware of things to improve and when the fix is complete, we'll issue a service release for the RI.

Regards,
Werner

Comment: This seems obsolete given your other answer. You can move the explanation there. There's a function to merge your accounts, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with release [1.0.1](https://bintray.com/unitsofmeasurement/maven/tec.units%3Aunit-ri/1.0.1) of the JSR 363 RI.